# how to install mavenGWT plugin in eclipse helios

Tags: gwt, maven

I have google this a lot but couldnt find any thing , how do we install mavenGwt plugin in our eclipse 
, i also manage to download this mavenGWt plugin , but how can i get this into my eclipse and define my archtype as mavengwt

or is there any eclipse plugin for mavenGwt which i can download from Install- new software in eclipse

thanks

Comment: What is this _mavenGwt plugin_ you're talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need anything special in Eclipse besides M2Eclipse (to work with any Maven project), and possibly the Google Plugin for Eclipse (which adds features related to GWT, whether you use Maven or not; and also auto-configures your Maven projects as GWT projects in Eclipse if they depend on `com.google.gwt:gwt-user` and use the `org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin plugin`).

Comment: Thanks , when i try to select archetype , i was expecting it to show org.codehaus.mojo.gwt-maven-plugin , but it never does ,How will i see this option , or What archetype should i select if i want to create a maven project which will also be a GWT project

Comment: For simple projects, see http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/WorkingWithMaven, for more complex projects, see https://github.com/tbroyer/gwt-maven-archetypes; I wouldn't advise using the gwt-maven-plugin archetype, YMMV.